# What is all default name of player in Just Dance game

Tags: just-dance-series

I'm looking for the player name of Just Dance, 
I have found "**Happy**", "**Jazzy**" and "**Funky**" but I don't found the other default name of player.

Someone know the other name ?

thanks

Comment: Lucky comes to mind :D

Comment: Crazy? I'm pretty sure it ends with Y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This screenshot shows several names:

[image: JD]

They appear to be:

- Happy
- Crazy
- Jazzy
- Funky
- Sunny
- Baby